# Change the values of state using for for-each and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [nav, setNav] = useState({
    firstPage: "active",
    secondPage: "deactive",
    navState: []
});
```

**This my state in context,**

```
const addNavi = (prop) => {

    let CurrentNavigation = nav.navState;

    if (!CurrentNavigation.includes(prop))
        CurrentNavigation.push(prop);

    setNav({ ...nav, navState: CurrentNavigation });

    CurrentNavigation.forEach(function (val) {
        if (val in nav) {
            setNav({ ...nav, val: "active" });
        }
    });
}
```

I send props from pages to here,
I wanna push those props into my array, also if that props in my nav, I also want to make their values to active,

**my props successfully add to the array but I won't change their values how can I fix this**

Comment: `function(val) { setNav({val:'active'}) }` -- I don't think this does what you might think it does. The 'val' that's being provided as a function argument is not actually going into that object that you're sending to `setNav`.

Comment: However, I do think you can do this: `function(val) { setNav({[val]:'active'}) }`

Comment: what is "if (val in nav) {" ?

Comment: @TKoL u save me dude I missed that [] thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

Do not update your state in every iteration. First add all of those nav:val pairs into a copy. after all iterations finished, set that copy to your state.

Comment: can u explain bit  or any reference cuz I am new to react